# PHP OOP & PDO get data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, oop, pdo

I'm learning OOP and PDO and I'v written class for database and class for users. I wrote registration method (I think correctly) So now I want to fetch all users with their data and use this public variables, which are in my class.

```
class Database{
    private static $_instance = null;
    private $_pdo,
            $_error = false,
            $_query,
            $_results,
            $_count;

    private function __construct(){
        try{
            $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.HOST.';dbname='.DBNAME,USERNAME,PASSWORD);
        }catch(PDOExeption $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static function getInstance(){
        if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
            self::$_instance = new Database();
        }
        return self::$_instance;
    }

    public function query($sql, $params = array()){
        $this->_error = false;
        $bindParamCounter = 1;
        if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
            if(count($params)){
                foreach ($params as $value) {
                    $this->_query->bindValue($bindParamCounter, $value);
                    $bindParamCounter++;
                }
            }
            if($this->_query->execute()){
                $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            }else{
                $this->_error = true;
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function insert($table, $params = array()){

        $paramsCounter = count($params);

            if($paramsCounter > 0){
                $i = 0;

                for($i = 0; $i < $paramsCounter; $i++){
                    $questionMarks[] =  '?';
                }

                    $paramsKeys = implode(', ', array_keys($params));
                    $questionMarks =  implode(', ', $questionMarks);
                    $sql =  'INSERT INTO '. $table.'('.$paramsKeys.')'." VALUES ({$questionMarks})";

            }
        return $this->query($sql, $params);
    }

    public function error(){
        return $this->_error;
    }
```

}

---

```
class Users{
    private $_pdo,
            $_data,
            $_userID,
            $_userPassword;

    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $firstname;
    public $last_name;

    public function __construct($user = NULL){
        $this->_pdo = Database::getInstance();
    }

    public function create($params = array()){
        try{
            $this->_pdo->insert('users', $params);
        }catch(PDOExeption $e){
            die($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function getAllUsers(){
        //get all users
    }
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Use the query method, that you wrote?

Comment: What's the problem you're having, exactly?  Have looked at the docs for the PDO library?  (Like this, for example http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

Comment: When exception occurs don't let is die easily.